# Removing a device from Android Device Manager for a specific account

Tags: google-account, android-device-manager

I work at a small phone repair chain. When I'm logged into the Gmail or Inbox apps with the company's shared Google e-mail account on my private phone, my phone is listed in Android Device Manager for the work account. This allows any and all of my colleagues to Lock or Erase my phone. No thank you.
My phone is an LG G4 running Marshmallow.

How can I remove (not hide) my phone from the Android Device manager for my work account and still receive e-mail on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- As [pointed out by OP](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/149584/removing-a-device-from-android-device-manager-for-a-specific-account#comment198094_154717) signing out of work account signs out of the *Gmail app and any other Google apps*. So there is **no way** to receive work mails *using Gmail or Inbox app*
- But you want to sign out to be outside the control of Android Device Manager, yet access company mails. For this, you would need to sign up on your device using your personal gmail account and use a *browser* for work account. You would need a *browser* that can send you notifications when mail is received on your work account.
- [Firefox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox&hl=en) can do this . Install [X-notifier lite](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/x-notifier-lite/) add-on to receive notifications. There are a couple of other Gmail add-ons but they did not get installed (you may like to try). This is a basic notifier that shows messages received in your notification tray
- Snapshot on left shows add on showing up in Firefox menu and on right the notification appearing in your notification tray

[image]
[image]

- This is verified by creating a test Gmail account and sending a mail to my personal (linked to Google Play) and it showed up on the notification. Further accounts are *not* added to Play Store or listed in the *accounts* section of *settings* as [OP had commented for another solution](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/149584/removing-a-device-from-android-device-manager-for-a-specific-account#comment191887_149594)

Comment: This is the one of the best answers so far. I suppose I could even use a third party mail client. A bit disappointing, since I really like the Google Inbox interface.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, it is very straightforward. 
Remove the work Google account from your phone and then add it to Gmail app as an **IMAP account** instead of a fully functional Google account.

If it is added as an IMAP account, it doesn't get linked to ADM or any other Google app, for that matter.

From [How to add Gmail account without adding Google account on Android - Gmail Community](https://support.google.com/mail/thread/16222360?hl=en)

> Instead of adding the account as a Google account, add it as type Personal (IMAP).  That way only Gmail will be connected.  The settings are:

```
Incoming servername:imap.gmail.com
Port: 993
Encryption: SSL
Outgoing server name: smtp.gmail.com
Port: 465
Encryption: SSL
```

Comment: I suppose this is my best course of action as of right now. I really like Inbox at the moment, but I'm not sure I like the trade-off.

Comment: Definitely the best answer.  If you want email, just use email.  Don't set it up as a broad-spectrum Google account on the device.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding more information to make it complete and helpful, the *how to do it* part

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what your after.

> To remove devices from your account: Use your phone's browser to go to
>   myaccount.google.com. In the "Sign-in & security" section, touch
>   Device activity & notification. In the "Recently used devices"
>   section, touch Review devices. Touch the device you want to remove >
>   Remove.

[Source](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6264236?hl=en)

Comment: That would also log me out of the Gmail app.

Comment: If your using Google Apps for Work then you can't. Basically to have the phone connected to a work account you would of had to agree on the device policy which would give them access to your device. That's for safety so for example a engineer or salesman loses there phone you can get rid of all the important data on there that phones so it doesn't fall into the wrong hands.

Comment: "Since I've logged into the Gmail app with the company's shared Google e-mail account on my private phone, my phone is listed in Android Device Manager for the work account" I'm surprised this question is still open its just how Google works. If you log in to a work account they have security in place which allows you to remotely wipe it. Simple.. If they made it so you could remove it from the device management that would eventually end in disaster.

Comment: Explain to me why wanting to receive my work email should logically result in that account being able to wipe my phone? I don't want to sync bookmarks or contacts, I just want to receive email.

Comment: When its a corporate email then they need to be able to wipe it. Say your a engineer who deals with important private information of a customer on a daily basis and whilst on your travels you lost that device with all that important data on. Your company wouldn't just sit there and say "oh well" they would of made sure they have some sort of extra security in place so that they can resolve the issue before it even becomes one. That's why so many companies are transferring to Google Apps for Work now as the level of security it provides is incredible.

Comment: I would say that the level of security is pretty bad when any of my fifteen colleagues can wipe my phone without any recourse.

Comment: Well it's better than you losing your phone and costing the company thousands.. I work in IT we have control over hundreds of phones but its not like we wipe them for the fun of it. You have nothing to worry about.. Unless you've installed something like PornHub we can see that ;)

Answer (score -1):

add your own account to your phone, remove the work account, then add the work account as a secondary email, not the playstore email.

Comment: All accounts I add to Gmail seem to get added to Play Store and the accounts listed in the Settings app as well.

Comment: from google support:
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3265955?hl=en

Comment: That just explains how to disable Android Device Manager for all accounts.