# Any option to get notification on new mail from Gmail delegate?

Tags: notifications, gmail

Recently I got access to a Gmail account as a [delegate](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/138350).

How can I get a notification when new mail arrives in this inbox of the delegated mail address?

[This](https://support.google.com/mail/forum/AAAAK7un8RUrp8Id1UXIhE) was asked in 2015, so I'm asking here to see if any changes have been made to make it possible.

Comment: I have no idea if this solution of using Mozilla helps http://android.stackexchange.com/a/154942/131553, since I haven't used a delegated email